# Sphinx can't run 'make html'

Tags: gtk, python-sphinx, gobject

I'm trying to **create the documentation** for my software by sphinx tool, so i've run `sphinx-quickstart`, and it's gone all ok.

Then i have to run **`make html`** (inside doc folder just created) and **i get an error**. I don't know how to fix this error:

```
Running Sphinx v1.2.2
loading pickled environment... not yet created
building [html]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] index                                                 
** (sphinx-build:2390): WARNING **: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion 'g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  import gobject._gobject
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: specified class size for type 'PyGtkGenericCellRenderer' is smaller than the parent type's 'GtkCellRenderer' class size
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_get_qdata: assertion 'node != NULL' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
make: *** [html] Ucciso
```

I've surfed the web and i prompted **`help('modules')`**:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion 'g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  import gobject._gobject
```

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of research suggests there are two problems here, which may or may not be related to each other but are both related to Ubuntu, which I think you must be running.

1. The "accessibility bus" may not be available if you haven't enabled Ubuntu's accessibility features. If you don't plan to do this, [the simple workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apport/+bug/1222356) is to run

   `export NO_AT_BRIDGE=1`

   at the shell prompt before running Sphinx. Alternatively  you can [add this setting under `/etc/env.d`](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-947210-start-0.html) and restart to make it permanent.

   With luck this will solve the entire problem, but in the likely case it doesn't:
2. There is [a known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/896836) with PyGTK on recent versions of Ubuntu that can produce the GTK warnings you're seeing (and frequently a segmentation fault as well). This [apparently has to do with](http://blog.rabbitvcs.org/archives/312) PyGTK transitioning from static to dynamic binding against the GTK library; if you create a situation where software attempts to use *both* types of binding simultaneously, it can trigger this problem.

   Apart from some ideas to try in [the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/896836) it seems there is no good solution yet.